# Anonymous website

Tags: anonymity

I want to publish some information in my country that is in the public domain that is in
a hard to read format.

What are some reasonable steps I could take to help ensure I am not identified or make it reasonably difficult.

Update:
To elaborate a bit the Government won't be coming after me, its their publicly posted data but I want to do a google maps mashup of the data.

The data in question is tax evaders and their home addresses, I just don't want one of them arriving at my front door and punching my lights out.

I don't think I have to go as far as the Tor network but just not be able to be traced as the owner of the site.

Comment: Want to stay anonymous? Don't ask questions about what you're doing on the SE network: http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/10/02/silk_road_s_dread_pirate_ross_ulbricht_asked_stack_overflow_question_under.html

Comment: If you aren't an expert, you're about 99.9999% likely to get caught (I'd only give the best experts a 50:50 chance). So either *don't do it* or accept that you *will be caught*.

Comment: The Tor network has a way to publish a website as a [hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en), if you're interested in hiding from ordinary people rather than governments, Tor should preserve your anonymity.

Comment: not doing anything ito have llegal, just don't want to have hassle from the people who's details i will be republishing

Comment: @JoeOD Unless you have done everything associated with posting this question using Tor, and are confident that Tor has been properly configured, forget about it. Everything includes creating the account that authenticates this SE account, creating this SE account, and posting the question and comment. It also includes all prior and future Internet activity using the computer being used.

Comment: Not to mention that the US government, and likely other governments, are rumored to run a large number of Tor relays and endpoints. Even Tor likely won't protect you except in the case of undeveloped countries.

Comment: @JoeOD it's not because the government released data that you are allowed to republish it. Furthermore, depending on where the person is residing, you can be held legally accountable for distributing personal data.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of free webhosters around which don't require more personal information than an email address. But these will usually only have a very restricted service and you won't have a proper domain name. They might also inject advertisement into your website.

When you want a domain name and proper webhosting, you will have to pay for it, and when you pay for something electronically, staying anonymous is hard.

It is possible to register domains "by proxy". That means that you ask a webhoster to register a domain for you. You have control over the website, but the company will be listed as responsible Admin-C in the WHOIS info of the registrar. You don't officially own the domain name that way which might put you into a bad situation when there is a dispute over the domain name, but when you don't care much about the domain name itself this might not be that important. Finding a webhoster which provides this service shouldn't be difficult with your favorite search engine.

This protects your identity from any civilians trying to find out who is behind the website. But keep in mind that law enforcement could force your service provider to tell them your identity when they have a search warrant. And they could get one when one of the people you list files a charge for slander.

Also note that most of the free webhosters and domain-by-proxy services don't like getting caught in the crossfire when someone has an issue with a website they host. That means when they receive a complaint, they will usually not hesitate for long before they take your website down. It's much less risky for them to lose a customer than to deal with a lawsuit.