# How to make the website owner anonymous?

Tags: anonymity, websites

1. Buying an international web domain (so there is no national law to expose its details beyond the domain registrar)
2. Not putting any personal and family name in the website

What else?

Comment: "WhoisGuard" will protect against domain owner lookups.  (no need to go outside your country for a web host)    Your web host and SSL provider would generally know who were, though, unless you used a fake identity.  I guess it boils down to "anonymous from who?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anonymous website](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48294/anonymous-website), [How can I keep my identity anonymous as a website owner/administrator?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/how-can-i-keep-my-identity-anonymous-as-a-website-owner-administrator).

Comment: Aren't you subject to the laws in the country where your server is physically located regardless of the DNS domain assigned to the site? Can your ISP be forced to provide details about their dealings with you?

Comment: @doneal24 I think the answer to both your questions is Yes.